# Datalabels of Chart JS can not display full values

Tags: chart.js

I am developing an angular app and using chartsjs and chartjs-plugin-datalable so that I can build horizontalBar.

[Current chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNIUW.png)

However, Some data is hidden and I can not resolve it.

This is config code

```js
    this.dataFill = {
        title: {
          display: false
        },
        legend: {
          position: 'right',
          display: false
        },
        scales: {
          xAxes: [
            {
              ticks: {
                beginAtZero: true,
              },
              display: false,
            }
          ],
          yAxes: [
            { display: false}
          ]
        },
        responsive: true,
        plugins: {
          datalabels: {
            anchor: 'end',
            align: 'end',
            rotation: 0,
            padding: 12,
            labels: {
              value: {
                color: '#000'
              }
            },
            font: {
              size: '12',
              weight: 'bold'
            }
          },
        }
       }
```

Comment: It looks like the labels do not fit in the canvas. Have you tried changing the canvas size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a custom plugin that mimics the [`grace`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/axes/cartesian/linear.html#grace) option that got introduced in v3, with this you can make sure your datalabels are always visible:

```js
Chart.plugins.register(ChartDataLabels);

var options = {
  type: 'horizontalBar',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 20, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderWidth: 1
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderWidth: 1
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    title: {
      display: false
    },
    legend: {
      position: 'right',
      display: false
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true,
        },
        //display: false,
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        display: false
      }]
    },
    responsive: true,
    plugins: {
      grace: {
        // grace: '10%', // add percentage of max and min to scale
        grace: 2, // add fixed number to min and max of scale
        hardMax: true // set suggestedMin/max or hard min/max
      },
      datalabels: {
        anchor: 'end',
        align: 'end',
        clamp: true,
        rotation: 0,
        padding: 12,
        labels: {

          clamp: true,
          value: {
            color: '#000'
          }
        },
        font: {
          size: '12',
          weight: 'bold'
        }
      },
    }
  },
  plugins: [{
    id: "grace",
    beforeLayout: (chart, options, c) => {
      let max = Number.MIN_VALUE;
      let min = Number.MAX_VALUE;
      let grace = options.grace || 0;
      let hardMax = options.hardMax || false;

      chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
        max = Math.max(max, Math.max(...dataset.data));
        min = Math.min(min, Math.min(...dataset.data));
      })

      if (typeof grace === 'string' && grace.includes('%')) {
        grace = Number(grace.replace('%', '')) / 100;

        chart.options.scales.xAxes.forEach((axe) => {
          if (hardMax) {
            axe.ticks.max = max + (max * grace);
            axe.ticks.min = min - (min * grace);
          } else {
            axe.ticks.suggestedMax = max + (max * grace);
            axe.ticks.suggestedMin = min - (min * grace);
          }
        })

      } else if (typeof grace === 'number') {

        chart.options.scales.xAxes.forEach((axe) => {
          if (hardMax) {
            axe.ticks.max = max + grace;
            axe.ticks.min = min - grace;
          } else {
            axe.ticks.suggestedMax = max + grace;
            axe.ticks.suggestedMin = min - grace;
          }
        })

      }

    }
  }]
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartjs-plugin-datalabels/1.0.0/chartjs-plugin-datalabels.js"></script>
</body>
```

Setting the `hardMax` option for the custom plugin to false will result in bigger white space in the end since it will prioritze nice tick spacement, set this to option to true and the bars have more space but the last tick space is a little off

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to put some padding in your ChartOptions:

```js
ChartOptions = {
    layout: {
      padding: {
        right: 25,
      },
    },
   }
```